Plotting Phase Portrait of Duffing Equation
I study a paper that describes a stationary problem where the function $\Phi_d$ satisfies the boundary conditions and is governed by a modified Laplace equation with a non-linear term. Here's a breakdown of the equations and the conditions they represent:

Equation Details:

The first equation:
$
 -k\Delta_d\Phi_d = \omega_d^2(\Phi_n - \beta \Phi_n^3$
This is a partial differential equation (PDE) where $\Delta_d$ denotes the Laplacian in $ d $ dimensions. The equation includes a linear term proportional to $\Phi_n$ and a non-linear term proportional to $ \Phi_n^3 $. The parameter $ k $ seems to modulate the influence of the spatial derivatives, while $ \omega_d $ and $ \beta $ scale the linear and non-linear terms, respectively.

Boundary conditions:
$
 \Phi_0 = \Phi_{K+1} = 0
 $
These conditions specify that $ \Phi $ is zero at the boundaries of the domain.



Special Case (Non-coupled Particles, $ k=0 $:

In the limit $ k = 0 $, the spatial derivative terms disappear, simplifying the equation to:
$
 \ddot{U}_n + \delta\dot{U}_n = \omega_d^2 U_n - \beta \omega_d^2 U_n^3
 $.
Here, $ U_n $ seems to represent the state of a system described by the Duffing equation, which is a well-known model for non-linear oscillators with a cubic nonlinearity. The term $ \delta \dot{U}_n $ introduces damping into the system, representing energy loss.



Here's the Mathematica code for simulating and visualizing the dynamics of the Duffing equation:
(* Parameters of the system *)
ωdSquared = 1;    (* ω_d^2 *)
β = 1;            (* β *)
δ = 0.01;         (* δ, damping coefficient *)

(* Duffing equation setup for use with NDSolve for simulation *)
duffingEquations = {U''[t] + δ U'[t] == ωdSquared U[t] - β U[t]^3, 
   U[0] == 0.1, U'[0] == 0};

(* Numerical solution of the equations for the trajectory *)
solution = NDSolve[duffingEquations, U, {t, 0, 100}];

(* StreamPlot for phase portrait *)
StreamPlot[{v, ωdSquared u - β u^3 - δ v}, {u, -1.5, 1.5}, {v, -1.5, 1.5}, StreamPoints -> Fine, 
 StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

(* Use ParametricPlot for the visualization of the trajectory from the solution *)
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{U[t], U'[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"U(t)", "U'(t)"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick]


And of course, it works as I want. My question is the following. Can I create on Mathematica a phase portrait like the one in the paper?

Could you give a link to the paper?

@AlexTrounev yes of course! It is in greek thought https://www.didaktorika.gr/eadd/handle/10442/45268?locale=en

Thank you very much. I have AI to translate Dynamics of nonlinear lattice systems: asymptotic behavior and study of the existence and stability of localized oscillations :)

@AlexTrounev what AI do you use?

We have several of them on https://www.docsie.io/ :)

The best what we can do with StreamPlot
(*Parameters of the system*)\[Omega]dSquared = 1;    (*\[Omega]_d^2*)
\[Beta] = 1;            (*\[Beta]*)
\[Delta] = 0.5;         (*\[Delta],damping coefficient*)

(*Duffing equation setup for use with NDSolve for simulation*)
duffingEquations = {U''[
      t] + \[Delta]  U'[t] == \[Omega]dSquared  U[
       t] - \[Beta]  U[t]^3, U[0] == x0, U'[0] == y0};

(*Numerical solution of the equations for the trajectory*)
solution = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
   duffingEquations, {U[t], U'[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {x0, y0}];

Show[StreamPlot[{v, \[Omega]dSquared  u - \[Beta]  u^3 - \[Delta]  \
v}, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
  StreamPoints -> {{{{-1.5, -1.5}, Blue}, {{1.5, 1.5}, 
      Blue}, {{.0255, .0251}, Red}, {{-.05, -.05}, Red}}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  StreamScale -> .15], 
 ParametricPlot[{Evaluate[ solution[.01, .01]], 
   Evaluate[ solution[-.01, -.01]], Evaluate[solution[-1.5, -1.5]], 
   Evaluate[solution[1.5, 1.5]]}, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"U(t)", "U'(t)"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Blue, Blue}]]



(+1) Very good to know that δ = 0.5;

@cvgmt Thank you. I actually chose this parameter by chance :)


Using ParametricNDSolve with {a,b} be the initial point.
We solve {U,U'} simultaneously( see the sol).
According to @Alex Trounev,  should be δ = 0.5;.

Clear["Global`*"];
ωdSquared = 1;
β = 1;
δ = 0.5;
duffingEquations = {U''[
      t] + δ U'[t] == ωdSquared U[t] - β U[t]^3, 
   U[0] == a, U'[0] == b};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[
   duffingEquations, {U, U'}, {t, 0, 100}, {a, b}];
draw[p_, L_, color_] := 
  ParametricPlot[{U[p[[1]], p[[2]]][t], U'[p[[1]], p[[2]]][t]} /. 
     sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, L}, PlotStyle -> color, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-2, 2, .5], Range[-2, 2, .5]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[1], Dotted}];
Show[draw[{-1.5, -1.5}, 25, Directive@{Dashed, Blue}], 
  draw[{0.01, 0}, 50, Red], draw[{-0.01, 0}, 50, Red], 
  draw[{1.5, 1.5}, 50, Green]] /. 
 Line[pts_] :> {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
   Arrowheads[Thread[{Medium, {.2, .5, .8}}]], Arrow[pts]}


